# How can I get three curves in one list plot from points of the form {x, y1, y2, y3}?

Tags: plotting

Can `ListLinePlot` be used as the following?:

```
ListlinePlot[{x1,y1,y2,y3},{x2,y4,y5,y6...}]
```

My goal is to plot with co-ordinates having three values of `y` for each value of the independent variable `x`.

How would I write the code to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1234]

data = RandomReal[1, {5, 4}] // Sort

(* {{0.0116446, 0.927266, 0.543757, 0.479332}, {0.245349, 0.759896, 
  0.984993, 0.217045}, {0.459017, 0.884729, 0.583854, 
  0.263973}, {0.876608, 0.521964, 0.0862234, 0.377913}, {0.91956, 
  0.423835, 0.98729, 0.587943}} *)

ListLinePlot[Transpose[Thread[{First[#], Rest[#]}] & /@ data],
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using Bob Hanlon's example:

```
SeedRandom[1234]

data = RandomReal[1, {5, 4}] // Sort;
```

You can also use [`TemporalData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemporalData.html) as follows:

```
td = TemporalData[Rest /@ data, {First /@ data}];

ListLinePlot[td]
```

[image]